# Can I change the formula of SAXPY function?

Tags: c++, gpgpu

I am new to GPGPU, and I have a confusion about SAXPY function:
The SAXPY function is like given two same sizes and type vector X and Y, do the operation that changes each element in Y: 
`y[i] = y[i]+a*x[i]`

I am not sure of can we change SAXPY's formula, like:
`y[i]=(y[i]+a)*(x[i]+c)`

but in this case, there is a new constant c, I have no idea how to call SAXPY in this condition.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: the difference is not a constant but `*` vs `+`, right?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thank you for the mention, I think I should change an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea how to call SAXPY in this condition.

You cannot.

Saxpy is abbreviation for ([nvidia docs](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/six-ways-saxpy/)):

> Single-Precision A·X Plus Y

A possible implementation is:

```
void saxpy(int n, float a, float * restrict x, float * restrict y)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      y[i] = a*x[i] + y[i];
}
```

If you want `y[i]=(y[i]+a)*(x[i]+c)`, then thats a different function. No matter how you transform your formula, saxpy cannot do the `x[i]*y[i]` part for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, is that ok to write a function like this: `void newfunc(int n, float a, float b, float * restrict x, float * restrict y)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      y[i] = (a+x[i]) * (b+y[i]);
}` Then call it by using `newfunc<<<num_blocks, block_size>>>(n,a,b,x,y)`?

Comment: @Konan i know nothing about GPGPU et al, I was just curious, read a bit, and thought i could share what I found as answer, thats why this answer is a bit vague

Comment: Thank you, I asked my professor after class and I think we cannot rewrite the function.